# Javascript - return selected value of a select MVC6 taghelper element using a function

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc

I am using ASP.NET core MVC6 so I'm using a select taghelper for the dropdown. This all works and I have a dropdown with states. As can be seen below there is a selected state.

In Javascript I wanted to get the selected value of this dropdown. I tried each of these:

```
        var getSelectedState1 = function () {
            return $State.val;
        };

        var getSelectedState2 = function () {
            return $("#State").val;
        };
```

..and both returned empty strings.

As "State" is the element ID of the state select element which I've identified both from [Dave Paquette's](http://www.davepaquette.com/archive/2015/05/13/mvc6-input-tag-helper-deep-dive.aspx) blog and also from the page source...

```
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="col-md-2 control-label" for="State">State:</label>
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <select class="form-control" data-val="true" data-val-required="A State name is required" id="State" name="State"><option value="NSW">New South Wales</option>
<option selected="selected" value="VIC">Victoria</option>
<option value="QLD">Queensland</option>
<option value="SA">South Australia</option>
<option value="WA">Western Australia</option>
<option value="TAS">Tasmania</option>
<option value="NT">Nothern Territory</option>
<option value="ACT">Australian Captial Territory</option>
</select>
            <span class="text-danger field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="State" data-valmsg-replace="true" />
        </div>
```

eg id="State".

Using a breakpoint and checking the value of  "getSelectedState" I get an empty return for both attempts.

How do I populate a variable "getSelectedState" with the selected value of the dropdown using a function?

Note: Whilst this is aimed at Javascript people the problem might be in relation to the fact that its an MVC6 Taghelper element and I'm not accessing it correctly - this might be why its returning "" and not the javascript.

Comment: `return $("#State").val();` (parenthesis after `val`)

Comment: Yes that worked. Thanks Stephen.